# Consulta sobre relacion en Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Estoy comenzando en Rails y no he podido dar con una relación.

Tengo 3 tablas: Video, donaciones y usuarios. Un usuario puede poner X videos y cada video puede tener varias donaciones.

- En video tengo el `user_id`
- En Donaciones tengo el `user_id` y `video_id`

Mis modelos son:

```
class Donation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :video
end

class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :donation
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :video
  has_many :donation
end
```

Puedo sacar el usuario de cada video sin problemas:

```
video.user.name
```

El problema se me da cuando quiero sacar el título del video de una donación:

```
 <% @donaciones.each do |d| %>
      <%= d.video.titulo %><br>
 <% end %>
```

Me da siempre:

```
undefined method `titulo' for nil:NilClass
```

El título está en la tabla `videos`, solo tengo 1 registro.

¿Hay alguna manera de poder ver la consulta completa que se está realizando en la página de error?

Comment: ¿Definiste `@donaciones` en algún lado? No lo veo en tu código

Comment: Si @donaciones es simplemente un Donation.all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código `donacion.video.titulo` lo que hace es mirar el valor del atributo `video_id` de la donación y buscar en la tabla videos el video correspondiente.

El problema es que en este caso el video no existe (porque fue borrado por ejemplo) o la donación no tiene un video asociado, en ese caso `donacion.video` es nil y obtenés ese error.

Para evitarlo, podés hacer la relación requerida (para evitar tener donaciones sin videos en la base de datos):

```
class Donation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :video, required: true
end
```

También deberías ver como evitar que se borren videos y dejen donaciones huerfanas, para eso tendrías que utilizar la opción `:dependent` en el has_many, según como quieras resolver el problema.

```
class Videos < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :donations, dependent: :restrict_with_exception
end
```

Por último, si no te importa el que no haya un video asociado, se puede utilizar un objeto nulo (del patrón "null-pattern") sobreescribiendo el método `video`:

```
class Donation < ActiveRecord::Base
  def video
    super || NullVideo
  end
end
```

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias, no entendía mucho los dependent, muy agradecido.